Firestore and Firebase Storage Not Working, Using Flutter for web development
I need help regarding to the Firestore and Firebase Storage.
At first before deploy i use command flutter run -d chrome all the firestore and firebase storage is functioning data, image or file is saved. but after deploy hosting , the firestore and firebase storage didnt save any data, image or file. i already deploy firestore, storage and hosting but still not working.
Here is the Firestore Rules

Firestore Rules

rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow read, write access to authenticated users for all documents
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    
    // Allow read access to the 'users' collection without authentication
    match /Users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}


Firebase Storage Rules

rules_version = '2';

// Craft rules based on data in your Firestore database
// allow write: if firestore.get(
//    /databases/(default)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}

Im expecting the data of the firestore and storage will be saved in firestore after deploy hosting using firebase.

Also, your Storage Rules do not allow read or write.

How do you know that the problem is caused by security rules?  We need to be able to see your code and any error message that's being generated from it.  Please edit the question to show all relevant debugging details.

Make sure you add the hosting domain to Authentication -> Settings -> Authorized Domains:


yes already did but still same thing hapen , just realize now , i try to register on the website , the information data is saved in the firestore but when i upload the image while register it didnt save in the firebase storage so that thing is block the data to be saved in the firestore. problem occurs when upload the image.
